# $ \int_{1}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = g(b)$ is there a method to find all functions $f$ that satisfy this equality?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a function, such that : 
$ \int_{1}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  = g(b)$

Now I would like to find all functions $f$ that satisfy this equality yet I don't really now how to proceed.

For exemple if we take : $g(b) = \frac{b^4-1}{b}$, then how can I find a function $f$ that satisfy :

$ \int_{1}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  = \frac{b^4-1}{b}$ for all $b > a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

EDIT : And more generally is there a method to find this kind of equality ?

Comment: Just take the derivative of both sides?

Comment: Isn't it just $f(x)=g'(x)$? This is just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f$ should be continuous, and assuming that $g$ is differentiable, we find by applying $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}$ to both sides
$$ f(b)=g'(b).$$

Also note that we necessarily need $g(1)=0$.

Comment: Ok, so if $g(1)$ is never equal to $0$ it means that the equation doesn't have any solutions ?